# Lucene block join query throwing ArrayOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, join, lucene

I am trying to use IndexTimeJoin feature of Lucene in one of my projects.
And when i do a ToParentBlockJoinQuery i am facing an exception.

```
[Exception: java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.apache.lucene.search.join.ToParentBlockJoinQuery$BlockJoinScorer.nextDoc(ToParentBlockJoinQuery.java:297)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.ConjunctionScorer.nextDoc(ConjunctionScorer.java:99)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.Scorer.score(Scorer.java:64)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:627)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:309)
```

The lucene version i am using is 4.5.0
The requirement is simple. 
Eg:
   I have an object Group, which in it will have multiple members.
   Each member in the group is indexed as child doc and the group is indexed as     parent doc.
All of them written to index using "updateDocuments" method of lucene index writer.

When I test this with some sample data it works fine. When in deployment a large amount of data is indexed I get this exception.

I am not currently able to figure out what kind of data could cause this issue with the information in the exception.

After debugging the code, i see the reason is that, in BlockJoinScorer.nextDoc method, the parentDoc is returned as -1. 
Does this mean that a child Doc is present in the index without a parent?

I would highly appreciate any pointers in the direction of what causes this kind of error.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Any pointers as to how to debug this further as well will be of great help

Comment: Check out [Luke](https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke/releases)
It's a useful tool to check what's actually in your index.

Comment: I did try it, but couldn't make much out of it because I am not fully aware of the structure of indexing done for this "BlockDocuments". Any insight on this structure?